# Can my android application modify files and documents stored on the device?

Tags: android

Is it possible to write an android application than can gain access to files and documents on an android device and modify them (delete if possible), not necessarily resource files used by the OS but general user documents, provided that the user of the device allowed the application to do this?

PS. This is not for any unethical use but for academic purposes. :)

Comment: Yes, anything on the sdcard, and non-private directories of the internal memory are fair game.

Comment: There are lot of third party filemanagers out here, So the question is not valid, you just type it in google and search you can get what ever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have the permission for it, you'll have no issues.

The OS segregates storage into two categories - [Internal and External](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html). Quoting the documentation:

> External storage is the best place for files that don't require access
>   restrictions and for files that you want to share with other apps or
>   allow the user to access with a computer.

In order to read and write files there, you'll need this permissions on your manifest file:

```
<manifest [...]>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

[`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) is API Level 4, but 'starting API level 19, this permission is not required to read/write files in your application-specific directories returned by [getExternalFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29)(String) and getExternalCacheDir()' - catch being that files that your application creates there are considered *private* to the application.